# In Netsuite REST, how do I assign an item location to an item line in a sales order?

Tags: rest, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm using Netsuite's Postman collection (which takes care of the Oauth1 stuff), and am POSTing to this endpoint:

```
{{proto}}://{{host}}/rest/platform/{{version}}/record/salesorder
```

... and the body is something like this:

```
{
  "customForm": "999",
  "entity": {
    "id": "1111"
  },
  "department": {
    "id": "2222"
  },
  "subsidiary": {
    "id": "33"
  },
  "otherRefNum": "TEST-PO",
  "location": {
    "id": "444"
  },
  "item": {
    "items": [
        {
          "item": { "id": "555555" },
          "inventorylocation": {  "id": "444" },
          "price": { "id": "-1" },
          "grossAmt": 999,
          "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to assign a location on the item level. The above request creates a sales order ok (without the line-level location assignment) if I remove the `inventorylocation` line, but with that in there, I get this error: `Unknown reference or subrecord field inventorylocation in request body.`

Netsuite's REST API documentation is here:
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2019.2/index.html#tag-salesorder

I have also tried substituting `location` and moving the fields around a bit, without success. (either the salesorder is created without a line-level location assignment, or I get an error similar to the above error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation you linked, it appears that the field id you need is `inventorylocation` rather than `itemlocation`.

> ### salesorder-itemElement
>
> ...
>   giftCertRecipientName Recipient Name: string
>   id [Missing Label:id]: string
>   inventorydetail: salesorder-item-inventorydetail
>   ***inventorylocation: location***
>   inventorysubsidiary: subsidiary
>   isClosed Closed: boolean
>   ...

Comment: Reference: https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2019.2/index.html#/definitions/salesorder-itemCollection

Comment: Good suggestion, but changing itemlocation to inventorylocation gives the same error. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2020.1/index.html#/definitions/salesOrder-itemElement) for a `salesOrder-itemElement`, it looks like that key is correct.

Have you tried the `"location": "{ID}"` variation?

In [LedgerSync](https://github.com/LedgerSync/ledger_sync) it looks like the request for creating an invoice results in this body:

```
{
    "entity": "309",
    "location": "1",
    "sublist": {
        "items": [
            {
                "amount": 12345,
                "description": "Test Line Item FLURYAOLJLFADYGR-1"
            },
            {
                "amount": 12345,
                "description": "Test Line Item FLURYAOLUFUTBYJD-2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

There also is a [`salesOrder-item-inventorydetail`](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2020.1/index.html#/definitions/salesOrder-item-inventorydetail) object that also contains a `location`.  Perhaps you could use that one like so:

```
{
  "customForm": "999",
  "entity": {
    "id": "1111"
  },
  "department": {
    "id": "2222"
  },
  "subsidiary": {
    "id": "33"
  },
  "otherRefNum": "TEST-PO",
  "location": {
    "id": "444"
  },
  "item": {
    "items": [
        {
          "item": { "id": "555555" },
          "inventorydetail": {
            "location": "444"
          },
          "price": { "id": "-1" },
          "grossAmt": 999,
          "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
  }
}
```